# получить значение из строки по ключу

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

всем привет!
есть строка вида:

> {'имя': 'вася', 'фамилия': 'пупкин', 'отчество': 'иванович'}, {'имя':
>   'коля', 'фамилия': 'иванов', 'отчество': 'игоревич'}, {'имя': 'петя',
>   'фамилия': 'петров', 'отчество': 'александрович'}

нужно преобразовать строку например в json или еще что-нибудь, чтобы я мог по ключу 'вася' получить его отчество например.
какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если хочется через json, то можно так:

```
import json


data = '''{'имя': 'вася', 'фамилия': 'пупкин', 'отчество': 'иванович'},
          {'имя': 'коля', 'фамилия': 'иванов', 'отчество': 'игоревич'},
          {'имя': 'петя', 'фамилия': 'петров', 'отчество': 'александрович'}'''

data = '[%s]' % data

data = data.replace("'", '"')

dct = {item['имя']: {'фамилия': item['фамилия'], 'отчество': item['отчество']}
       for item in json.loads(data)}

res = dct['вася']['отчество']

print(res)
```

Comment: через json это как вариант, первое что на ум пришло. есть более лаконичный метод, даже с использованием других модулей?

Comment: Лаконичнее - вряд ли. Но для более-менее серьёзных проектов я бы всё-таки вручную парсил исходную строку. Больше мороки при разработке, но меньше геморроя в эксплуатации и поддержке.

Comment: Ну или как вариант стоит посмотреть в сторону pandas.

Comment: @Александр, для Pandas нужени либо словарь либо CSV, но не такая строка

Answer (score 2):

Модуль [YAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) допускает небольшие неточности в JSON - такие, например, как одиночные кавычки вместо двойных:

```
In [40]: import yaml

In [41]: d = yaml.safe_load(f'[{data}]')

In [42]: d
Out[42]:
[{'имя': 'вася', 'фамилия': 'пупкин', 'отчество': 'иванович'},
 {'имя': 'коля', 'фамилия': 'иванов', 'отчество': 'игоревич'},
 {'имя': 'петя', 'фамилия': 'петров', 'отчество': 'александрович'}]
```